# Switching from MySQL to MYSQLi - loop not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm changing my site from using mysql to mysqli. So far the changes have been quite simple but I have a calendar page with for loops which doesn't work after the switch. I'm pretty sure it's the loop which is causing the error, but I can't seem to find a fix.

Here's a selection of the code, which works with the mysql_query (which I have commented out) but doesn't with the mysqli->query

```
<?php include("conn.php");

$today = mktime(12,0,0,date("m"),1,date("Y"));
$currentmonth = date(m, $today);
$currentyear = date(Y, $today);
$prevmonth = $currentmonth - 1;
$prevyear = $currentyear;
$prevdate = mktime(12, 0, 0, $prevmonth, 1, $prevyear);
$pdim = date("t", $prevdate);

function showMonth($month, $year, $pdims, $prevmonths, $prevyears)
{
$caldate = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$offset = date("w", $caldate);
$pdimsplus = $pdims + 1;
$enddays = $pdimsplus - $offset;

for($i = 1; $i <= $offset; $i++)
{   
$qryhead1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE day(date) = $enddays AND month(date) = $prevmonths AND year(date) = $prevyears LIMIT 1";

//$res1 = $mysqli->query($qryhead1);
//$noofrec1 = $res1->num_rows;
//if ($noofrec1 > 0) {    
//while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_object($res1)) {

$res1 = mysql_query($qryhead1);
$noofrec1 = mysql_num_rows($res1); 
if ($noofrec1 > 0) {
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_object ($res1)) {
    $id = $row1->id;
    $image = $row1->image; ?>
    <div><?php print("$enddays"); ?><a href="<?php print("$id"); ?>"><img src="/images/<?php print("$image"); ?>"></a></div>
    <?php } 
    } else { ?>
    <div><?php print("$enddays"); ?></div>
    <?php }
    $enddays++;
    }
}
?>

<div>
<?php showMonth($currentmonth, $currentyear, $pdim, $prevmonth, $prevyear); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Fetch into array, then try foreach.

Comment: In include("conn.php"); have you created a mysqli object?

Comment: did you change the connection you make in the included file? if `mysql_query` is still working, chances are you're not connecting using `mysqli_*`

Comment: It's allways good to just debug a bit more. For example, do a var_dump on $row1 to see what you got there. Debugging solves many questions!

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_fetch_object` (part of the procedural interface) whereas the rest of your code seems to be using the object interface?

Comment: @fvu I think I tried so many different fixes that the code became somewhat mixed! Thanks for pointing it out though - I'm now going to check the rest of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `$mysqli` object (I'm assuming that you created one in conn.php), you're not passing it in as a function parameter for your custom function `showMonth()`. Have a read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: That was exactly it - I added my $mysqli into my showMonth() function and it now works - I don't think I would have figured that out without your pointer so thanks. Follow up question, why would that be necessary in mysqli yet it worked without with mysql?

Comment: @timsnell mysql_query is an inbuilt PHP function, whereas $mysqli is a custom object that you created.